# Javascript tic-tac-toe winner check

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

Code for the tic tac toe:

```
$(".square").one("click", function() { 
if( gameOver == false ) {
 sq1 = $("#sq1").text(); // grabs the value of squares after being clicked.
 sq2 = $("#sq2").text(); 
 //same for all 9 squares
}

//To check winner : (Result is same but code is broken into statements to avoid length.)
function checkWinner() {
if(  sq1 != emptyStr && (sq1 == sq2 && sq2 == sq3) ) { //emptyStr = ""
    winner = 1; //Testing purposes
    //alert(winner);
}

else if( sq1 != emptyStr &&  (sq1 == sq4 && sq4 == sq7) ) {
    winner = 1;
    //alert(winner);
}
```

My question is ..how should I go about calling checkWinner function. Should it be called upon every click or should setInterval be used?

2nd question : If I run checkWinner in console and the conditions are true, winner becomes 1 **after** an extra click and not at the same time.

Edit: Code as requested by @sra :

```
//2 buttons( x and o)
$("#x").on("click", function() {
  gameOver = false;
  player = 1;
  $("#o").attr("disabled","disabled");
})

$("#o").on("click", function() {
  gameOver = false;
  player = 2;
  $("#x").attr("disabled","disabled");
})
```

(Checked other questions with same keywords but couldn't find my answer)

P.S. Still a novice at JavaScript, so feel free for code improvement suggestions and edits!

Comment: you need a check just after an action.

Comment: just a little improvement on your code, `sq1 == sq2 && sq2 == sq3` could be compressed to `sq1 == sq3`, the same thing for your other check.

Comment: @KevinKloet that wouldn't work, since you shouldn't win if sq2 is not the same as sq1 and sq3

Comment: sorry, i can not help, i don't know jquery.

Comment: @NinaScholz I defined a counter and increased it after every click. On 5th click, I ran checkWinner (since 5 is the min. number of moves required to win). But winner becomes 1 only after an extra click,i.e. 6th click(one more click after 3 squares have matched.). I've made an edit about it as the 2nd question.

Comment: @NinaScholz That's alright, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @KevinKloet sorry, but that also doesn't work. it would actually do something like `sq1 == (sq2 == sq3)` -> `sq1 == true` -> `false`.  You can do that in coffeescript though, I also tried it this way first ;)

Comment: my bad, tried it only with 1 and 2 as values :)

Answer (score 1):

You should totally check whenever a click happens. This is when you need to evaluate the new state (is there a winner?, has the game ended in a draw?).

To keep the actual matching-logic a little smaller I would do something like this:

```
didPlayerWin = function(player) {
  sq1 = $("#sq1").text() == player;
  sq2 = $("#sq2").text() == player;
  sq3 = $("#sq3").text() == player;
  // ... for all the squares

  sq1 && sq2 && sq3 ||
  sq4 && sq5 && sq6 ||
  sq7 && sq8 && sq9 ||
  // ... for all the possible wins
}

$(".square").on("click", function() {
  if (didPlayerWin("x")) {
    alert("x rockz!");
  } else if (didPlayerWin("o")) {
    alert("o rockz!");
  } else {
    // check if all the squares are filled
  }
}
```

For the second part of your question (you needing to do an extra click to get the winner evaluated), I think that when you check the winner, the actual DOM Element that the user clicked hasn't yet updated to the new value. So when do you set the clicked DOM Elements text to "x" or "o"? Can you also post that code?

Comment: Sorry for the late response...added the code you requested. Also, should I keep a counter for every click on the square and when counter == 5 || counter > 5, checkwinner runs(since 5 is the minimum number of moves required to win the game)?

Comment: Yeah, you could and it would save the code from being run an extra 5 times. But at the other side of the argument, it's client side Javascript and it's only a small piece of code and personally I wouldn't bother even doing a pre-check. (If it was server side through, I would)